# Should I code my website in HTML5 in 2013?

Tags: html, css

I've started learning and researching HTML5, I only ever studied HTML classic some 6 years ago and I never got quite far with it.
I want to build a website and publish it to the WWW.
Should I stick with HTML4 for now? Or should I just jump straight into HTML5?

I've read & I understand that a lot of the new elements are not supported, but I feel a bit stupid to type outdated tags. Are HTML5 elements more supported in 2013?

Is it better to just start with 5 now, as the future is HTML5?
I've also started doing CSS3 and I think it would benefit me rather than CSS2.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Learn HTML5 is good choice..

Comment: The field is changing *really* fast so check your sources. If they're more than 6 months old, they're outdated.

Comment: Most modern browsers support most of HTML5: http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you give "The truth about html5" a read if you have the time.

Html5 so to speak offers a lot of new stuff. But the reality of the market is a bunch of stuff either just plain works with a handful of browsers,  and other stuff has been around for years and simply got included under the so to say html5 branding.

Also keep in mind that ie8 still represents a huge piece of the pie of the ie landscape and will do so for years to come. In the end it all comes down to what your project target audience is and how many percent of users you are willing to sacrifice or allowed to sacrifice.

[Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) should be of good use to you, and understanding when and how too use polyfills too.

Myself I manage a big site which uses a bunch of html5, css3,  and responsive design that scales from mobile phones to tablets to desktops, and works just fine in ie7 too.

But it didn't suffice to say hey let's code it in html5,  but instead took a lot of reflection and compromises to get there.

So actually my answer would be: use the parts of css3 that degrade gracefully as much as you like. The parts of html5 that you find indispensable ..at the condition you have a fallback polyfill in place.  And the rest ..think 20 times before jumping on the buzzword bandwagon.

In the end you don't even have to choose between html4/5 or css2/3. You can mix and match both easily .. as the latter simply build on the previous. As long as you know what you are doing, and why.

But yes learn it !

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I will use the site you mentioned, I think I will start coding with HTML5 as well as HTML4 and mix and match, and use HTML5 for tags that aren't available in 4 :)

Thank you again.

Comment: Using html5 specific tags will break ie6-8 layout without html5 shim. A tag is nothing more than a prestyled element. Set a span to display:block and you now have a div, set a div to display:inline and you now have a span ..you get the picture. I wouldn't worry too much about tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should code your website in a language that meets your website's requirements.

What I mean by this is if your proposed website will include features of html 5, then you should write it in html 5.

You could most probably achieve the same or a similar effect using html 4, but why go to the bother when html 5 has built in features to help you.

I personally would use html 5 anyway as you are essentially future proofing your project for some years to come.

Also use CSS3 but just check the availability of rules in browsers.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to code what I can and what's needed in HTML5 and the rest in 4, Thank you also for the heads up about CSS3 :)